# String to JSONArray returns null for some reason

Tags: java, json

I have a URL that retuns a JSON back and I first convert it to String and then convert it to JSONArray but for some reason, it's returning null. 
The sample url looks like this: 
https://data.phila.gov/resource/sspu-uyfa.json?dispatch_date=2017-08-01

Below is my code:

```
public JSONArray getJsonFromUrl(final String data_url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(data_url).openStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) { 
        sb.append((char) cp); 
    }
    is.close();
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
    return jsonArray;
}
```

So the StringBuilder object `sb` is not null. When I debug, I can see it is a huge string. But it's `new JSON(sb.toString());` that returns `null`. Also, I tried replacing `JSONArray` with `JSONObject` and still same issue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Try JSON Parser to parse the data, for e.g, JsonArray jsonArray = new JsonParser().parse(rd).getAsJsonArray();

Comment: the url shows syntax error in your json data...

Comment: @Tehmina JsonParser() didn't work either.

Comment: @Androidjack-RajeshGosemath I validated the JSON using online Json validators and it turns out to be valid. Can you tell me what part shows syntax error?

Answer (score 0):

your data has a SyntaxError. in near column 48697,
H have find the bad data segment:
,"ucr_gen1447C3FA9C2915241",

I think you would like :
,"ucr_general":"1447C3FA9C2915241",

Comment: When I pasted the output of the url into a few online JSON Validators, it says the Json is valid. I am not sure where the syntax error is.

Comment: the "ucr_general" field is loss in column: 48697 (json: https://data.phila.gov/resource/sspu-uyfa.json?dispatch_date=2017-08-01)